# LiquiBase is throwing UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Cannot find LockService

Tags: liquibase, installanywhere

I am trying to get LiquiBase to work with InstallAnywhere.  InstallAnywhere is executing LiquiBase via an ANT target.

It work fine if the ANT target is executed via command line. When I use InstallAnywhere I get the error below.  I can't seem to get InstallAnywhere to spit out verbose logging.  InstallAnywhere is using ANT 1.71 jars.  I used ANT 1.71 via command line, it worked without any issues.

LiquiBase version is 3.4.2

> WARNING 11/4/16 11:28 AM: liquibase: Unknown database: Microsoft SQL Server
>   build exception
>   C:\ProgramFiles\MyApp\database\sql\build.xml:301: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Cannot find LockService for unsupported
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.AntUtility.go(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.AntRunner.installSelf(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallablePiece.install(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.InstallDirectory.install(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.InstallDirectory.install(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallablePiece.install(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.GhostDirectory.install(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallablePiece.install(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.Installer.install(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.InstallProgressAction.ae(Unknown Source)
>       at com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.ProgressPanelAction$1.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Cannot find LockService for unsupported
>       at liquibase.lockservice.LockServiceFactory.getLockService(LockServiceFactory.java:79)
>       at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:195)
>       at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
>       at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:327)
>       at liquibase.integration.ant.DatabaseUpdateTask.executeWithLiquibaseClassloader(DatabaseUpdateTask.java:35)
>       at liquibase.integration.ant.BaseLiquibaseTask.execute(BaseLiquibaseTask.java:81)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       ... 16 more

I am getting this error because SQL URL is not formed correctly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: LIquibase tries to identify your db based on the db connection which is based on your configuration for the db. So yes it seems legit that you db url or other settings for the db connection are not correct. You could set logging to debug leve. That might give you hints on what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Based on the error ** liquibase: Unknown database: Microsoft SQL Server**.  It can tell that my connection is a MS SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Was off the task for a while. Back again.

Based on the error **liquibase: Unknown database: Microsoft SQL Server**.  It can tell that my connection is a MS SQL Server.

I took a look at the code, DatabaseFactory looks for classes that extends/implements Database.class.  That is store in the **implementedDatabase** map.  If that map is correctly populated, it should've found it via the MSSQLDatabase.isCorrectDatabaseImplementation() method because it is trying to match on **Microsoft SQL Server** for the conn.getDatabaseproductName()

Comment: That's the theory. :) The question is why does it not work this way... Turning on debug logging could reveal something...